# Center multiple divs in another div?

Tags: html, css

I have four divs contained in another div, and I want the four inner divs to be centered.

I have used `float: left` on the four divs so that they are horizontally aligned.

CSS:

```
<style>
    .square  //inner divs
    {
        float: left;
        margin:1pt;
        width:72pt;
        height:72pt;
    }
    .container //outer divs
    {
        text-align:center;
        width:450pt;
        height: 80pt;
    }
</style>
```

and HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "square">...</div>
    <div class = "square">...</div>
    <div class = "square">...</div>
    <div class = "square">...</div>
</div>
```

How can I center the divs inside the container?

The number of inner divs can be variable.

Comment: Tangential: does having spaces between class, equals sign, and quoted value not cause any problems?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's an alternate method if you can use an extra div:

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class="centerwrapper">
    <div class = "square">...</div>
    <div class = "square">...</div>
    <div class = "square">...</div>
    <div class = "square">...</div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
    .square
    {
        float: left;
        margin:1pt;
        width:72pt;
        height:72pt;
    }
    .container
    {
        text-align:center;
        width:450pt;
        height: 80pt;
    }
    .centerwrapper
    {
       margin: auto;
       width: 302pt;
    }
</style>
```

Also, make sure you have a closing quote on your `<div class = "container">` there.  The code you pasted is missing one.

Comment: This works for 4 divs, but the number of divs in the container may not always be the same. In my case, sometimes only 2 or 3 divs may appear, and I want them to be centered as well. I forgot to specify this in my question...

Comment: Hmm.  It might be better if you can get away with displaying your squares inline with a given width, instead of floating them.  If you can use margin: auto; in a surrounding div, then they will always be centered - the trick is getting away from specifying the width of it.

Comment: Ok, I managed to make it work by defining the width of the centerwrapper like this, instead of using a css class: 

<div style = "margin:auto; width:<?php echo 74*$nbDiv ?>pt">

Comment: How would  you do this without a width for `.centerwrapper`. As in, you have a dynamic array of `.squares`

Comment: That helped me a great deal. I was having the hardest time horizontally aligning divs for cross browser compatibility, and it ended up being really simple. All I had to do was follow the same div structure as above, specify width and display:block properties in the container, then for each child div, give it a percentage for width, float it to the left, and I was good to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 60):

Because you don't know the number of divs you have, you should use

`text-align:center` on the outer div

`display:inline-block` on then inner div

http://jsfiddle.net/edi9999/yv2WY/

**HTML**

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "square">John</div>
    <div class = "square">Mary</div>
    <div class = "square">Doe</div>
    <div class = "square">Jane</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.square
{
    margin:1px;
    width:20%;
    text-align:left;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display:inline-block;    
}
.container
{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height: 80pt;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Slightly updated version of your jsfiddle (you originally had inline-block on the container too, which isn't necessary): http://jsfiddle.net/yv2WY/34/

Answer (score 8):

Instead of floating the .square divs, give them `display: inline-block.` This might be dodgy in Firefox 3.0.x but I believe inline-block is fully supported in 3.5.x.

Comment: You'll need to put in a special rule for IE6/7 I believe as well.

Comment: Aha -- what I forgot is that IE6&7 only support inline-block on elements that were originally inline... so you'd have to change the .square divs into spans for this to work. Sorry.

Comment: With a bit of extra CSS you can make this happen without changing the markup. Here's the code I use (thanks to several others) that works on IE6+ and all the other modern browsers:

.inline-block {
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  #display: inline;
  /* fixes alignment against native input/button on IE6 */
  #vertical-align: auto;
}

If you are like me and no fan of hacks, you can take those last two properties out and move them into an IE stylesheet called by conditional comments (and remove the hash tags).

Answer (score 8):

As #RwL say, using `<span>` works, here a sample code, tested on IE6/8, Chrome, Safari, Firefox:

> CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* borders and width are optional, just added to improve visualization */
    .parent
    {
        text-align:center;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .child
    {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

> HTML

```
<span class="parent">
    <span class="child">
        A
    </span>
    <span class="child">
        B
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: However, if you need to ad UL lists inside, that will make it not CSS compliant, since UL is not allowed inside SPAN. In that case you can use conditionals and apply SPAN for IE6 (its not already standard anymore, cannot be more "not-standard" because this!), and DIV for others.

Comment: Also, parent can be DIV, only child needs to be SPAN so IE6 can detect the inline-block attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Most elegant solution I could find when you have a dynamic number of div to center is to use
`text-align: center;` on the parent div, and `display: inline-block;` on the children.

It's all explained in details [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/center-multiple-divs/).

Answer (score 2):

Simply place `margin:auto;` for all subsequent divs inside your main wrapper that is `text-align:center;`. SHOULD allign all child divs to the center of the parent div i think?

Comment: on top of this, if you needed spacing on the top/bottom of each child div you could use: margin: 5px auto 5px auto; the order for margin being: top left bottom right;

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help:

```
<style>
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/bfk5o34v/1/)

### All in one HTML element in auto center

This code apply all over HTML element in Center without any @mediaquery.

- The HTML element auto center main css property display inline-block of the  chide div and add css property text-align center of parent div

---

```css
.center {
            border: 1px groove;
            width: 97px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 122px;
            margin-left: 12px;
            margin-top: 13px;
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;

            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            color: #000000;
            background: #dbdbdb;
        }
```

```html
<div style="width: auto;text-align: center;">

            <div class="center">Div1</div>
            <div class="center">Div2</div>
            <div class="center">Div3</div>
            <div class="center">Div4</div>
            <div class="center">Div5</div>
            <div class="center">Div6</div>
            <div class="center">Div7</div>

    </div>
```

[see this example click here](https://jsfiddle.net/bfk5o34v/1/)